# add transition effect in ionic using angular animate

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I am new to the ionic platform. I want to add the some animations like drop down list but it does not take the transition. Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can take help of the following code snippet to add transition effects in ionic 2/ionic 3. It is an example of sliding transition effect.

```
import {Component, trigger, state, style, transition, animate} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      state('in', style({
        transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)'
      })),
      state('out', style({
        transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)'
      })),
      transition('in => out', animate('400ms ease-in-out')),
      transition('out => in', animate('400ms ease-in-out'))
    ]),
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

  toggleMenu() {

  }
}
```

Reference - https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-animate-creating-sliding-side-navigation/